# How do I use the Plaid exit function provided by the usePlaidLink?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plaid

I'm working on an app that logs a user out after a specified time of inactivity. I have an AuthContext that keeps track of the user's authentication state. I try to exit the PlaidLink modal when the app logs the user out using the [exit function](https://plaid.com/docs/link/web/#exit) from `react-plaid-link`. The issue is, calling the exit function does nothing. Here's my current implementation.

```js
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { usePlaidLink } from "react-plaid-link";
import { LinkedAccountsDispatchContext } from "../hooks/linkedAccountsContext";
import { AuthContext } from "../hooks/authContext";
import Button from "../components/Button";

const PlaidLink = ({
  linkToken,
  updateMode,
  className,
  accountId,
  plaidButtonName = "Link accounts",
  onClick = () => {},
}) => {
  const { createLinkedItem, updateExpiredItem } = useContext(
    LinkedAccountsDispatchContext
  );
  const { logged } = useContext(AuthContext);
  async function handleSuccess(publicToken) {
    await createLinkedItem(publicToken);
  }
  async function handleUpdateSuccess() {
    await updateExpiredItem(accountId);
  }
  const onSuccess = useCallback(handleSuccess, [createLinkedItem]);
  const onUpdateSuccess = useCallback(handleUpdateSuccess, [
    accountId,
    updateExpiredItem,
  ]);
  const config = {
    token: linkToken,
    onSuccess: updateMode ? onUpdateSuccess : onSuccess,
  };
  const { open, ready, exit } = usePlaidLink(config);
  const handleClick = () => {
    onClick();
    open();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!updateMode || !ready) {
      return;
    }
    open();
  }, [ready, updateMode, open]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!logged) {
      // This does nothing.
      exit({ force: true });
    }
  }, [logged, exit]);

  return updateMode ? null : (
    <Button onClick={handleClick} disabled={!ready} className={className}>
      {plaidButtonName}
    </Button>
  );
};

export default PlaidLink;
```

Please what's the right way to use the exit function in this context?

---

Update:

Trying out the vanilla js version also gives the same issue.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
const { open, exit } = Plaid.create({
  token: "GENERATED_LINK_TOKEN",
  onSuccess: (public_token, metadata) => {},
  onLoad: () => {},
  onExit: (err, metadata) => {},
  onEvent: (eventName, metadata) => {},
});

btn.addEventListener('click', async() => {
  open();
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('...exiting');
    exit({
      force: true
    });
  }, 15000);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="favicon.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <script src="https://cdn.plaid.com/link/v2/stable/link-initialize.js"></script>
  <title>Plaid Link Demo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="btn">Link Account</button>
  <script type="module" src="./js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From a purely Plaid perspective, I don't see anything wrong with your call to exit. Have you confirmed (e.g. using console.log statements) that the line

`exit({ force: true });`

is actually being reached?

Comment: I can confirm it is actually reached. Notice in the vanilla JS version, I placed a call to alert. The alert fires but the plaid modal stays open.

Answer (score 0):

Ran this by a co-worker and got an answer:

The exit function is indeed being called but not on Plaid Link. I replicated this and was able to call `exit()` by triggering it through the `onEvent` callback. Since the `onEvent` callback is passed into the config, Link is able to see that and close the modal.

When asked for clarification, he adds:
I created a piece of state called inactive at the top of the file which is initially set to false and within the onEvent() callback, when the "OPEN" event is returned, I triggered the inactive state to true just to simulate an inactive user. After where the config is created, I made use of the useEffect() hook and within it, put a setTimeout() function that said, if inactive is true, call exit(). Therefore the onEvent() callback actually in turn triggers the exit() function

```
const [inactive, setInactive] = useState(false);
```

```
  const onEvent = useCallback((event, metadata) => {
    console.log("onEvent", event, metadata);
    if (event === "OPEN") {
      setInactive(true);
    }
  }, []);

  const config = {
    token: token,
    onSuccess,
    onExit,
    onEvent,
  };

  const { open, ready, error, exit } = usePlaidLink(config);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inactive) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        exit();
      }, 5000);
    }
  });
```

Comment: Well. I'm not sure how to go about this. Since the `config` is required to get the exit function from plaid, how can I call it (exit) before even having access to it?

Comment: I updated my answer to include additional details and a code snippet -- does that help at all?